# delete and return all items in an array

Tags: ruby

Is there a helper method to delete all items from an array and return those items in ruby?

For example,

```
array = [{:a=>1, :b=>2},{:a=>3,:b=>4},{:a=>5,:b=>6}]
```

and I want to delete all the array elements and return them so I can do some processing on those elements?

Comment: Just use the elements and then delete them later?

Comment: uhh, you could `array.each do |element|` to perform the processing, then when you're done you could do `array = []` to remove all elements in the array.  Hard to give a more specific answer without some context though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array = [{:a=>1, :b=>2},{:a=>3,:b=>4},{:a=>5,:b=>6}]
while element = array.pop do
  # process element however you like...
end
array    # => []
```

or use `shift` rather than `pop` if order matters to you.

Answer (score 2):

Do as below using [***`Array#shift`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) to delete the array content in one shot and return its elements:

```
array = [{:a=>1, :b=>2},{:a=>3,:b=>4},{:a=>5,:b=>6}]
array.shift(array.size)
# => [{:a=>1, :b=>2}, {:a=>3, :b=>4}, {:a=>5, :b=>6}]
array
# => []
```

If you want to delete one by one,you can do as below using [***`Array#delete_if`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
array = [{:a=>1, :b=>2},{:a=>3,:b=>4},{:a=>5,:b=>6}]
array.delete_if do |e|
    #do your work with e
    true
end
array # => []
```

Another approach is do your work first with the array and then delete all the elements from the array:

```
array = [{:a=>1, :b=>2},{:a=>3,:b=>4},{:a=>5,:b=>6}]
array.each do |e|
    #do your work with e
end
array.clear
array # => []
```

Comment: Good. Need to add this to 2.2: `def stomp(s) s.shift(s.size) end`.  In choosing the name, I was thinking of a teenager eyeing a mustard packet on the floor at McDonald's.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you have a great of sense of humor !! :)